# Jenkins on ISPConfig

Tags: linux, jenkins

I'm usin ISPConfig to have multiple domains for my clients. Now, I have Jenkins to deploy an specific project.

Jenkins has assigned the working directory on /var/www/myproject/web which it is the VirtualHost on ISPConfig.

Manually I have to:

```
chown -R jenkins:nogroup /var/www/myproject/web
> Build Jenkins project
chown -R web38:client17 /var/www/myproject/web
```

Questions:

- Is ok if I grant sudo permissions to Jenkins?
- Instead of that, should I create a bash script with sudo permissions?
- Is any permission role that I didn't notice to do this properly?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've found.

Install "Batch tasks" module on Jenkins.

Create an script as follows with root:root permissions on /var/www/your_domain.com/jenkins-post-build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE=$1
TARGET=$2

echo Moving $SOURCE to $TARGET

rm -rf $TARGET
cp -R $SOURCE $TARGET
ln -s $TARGET/build $TARGET/public/build
chown -R web39:client11 $TARGET
```

Add a Post Build action using the "Invoke batch tastsk"

```
sudo /var/www/your_domain.com/jenkins-post-build.sh ${WORKSPACE} /var/www/your_domain.com/web
```

Add this script right sudo permissions

```
Cmnd_Alias HIPER_DEV    = /var/www/your_domain.com/jenkins-post-build.sh
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:HIPER_DEV
```